# I am making a text-based RPG, and you can say yes or no on each screen, and I need help removing the eventlistener

Tags: javascript, window, removeeventlistener

So, I have a function that checks if you pressed 'n' or 'y', when you press 'n', a figure attacks you, after it is supposed to remove the event listener, and then give you a chance to win the fight, but before that there is a screen that says press any key to continue, but that screen doesn't show. Help?

I've been working on this for a while, and it just wont work, it doesn't remove the event listener.

This is the start screen code, after naming your character and stuff

`document.body.innerHTML = "<h4>As you are walking to the bar at a pub, a dark, hooded figure, pulls you aside to a corner: 'Listen, I have a job for you...'</h4><h2>Press 'Y' to accept, and 'N' to turn back to the bar</h2><img id='hoodedFigure' src='https://render.fineartamerica.com/images/rendered/default/print/6.125/8.000/break/images-medium/the-hooded-figure-kayleigh-semeniuk.jpg'>";`

//Then it adds the event listener:

`var event1 = window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);`

//This is the function it calls:

````
        {if (evt.keyCode == "89") {
        changeContentOnPressY(1);
    } if (evt.keyCode == "78") {
changeContentOnPressN(1);
    }}}```

//Then it calls this function to change the screen:

```function changeContentOnPressN(num) {
        if (num == 1) {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
    document.body.innerHTML = "The strange figure draws his weapons and agresses on you. You draw your small blade, and attempt to slash his stomach.<h3 style='text-align:center;'>Press any key to continue...</h3>";
            window.addEventListener("keydown", chance(1), false);
        } if(num == 2) {
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed2, false);
document.body.innerHTML = ""; // for 2nd n path}}```

//This is the part that is not working:

```window.removeEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);```

This is the chance() function:

```function chance(num) {
    if (num == 1) {
        var chance = Math.random(0.1, 1);
 if (chance >= 0.80) {
 document.body.innerHTML = "Suddenly a swaggering figure walks towards you he says intrduces himself as Jean-Jacques le Tourment des Ombres, Grand Connoisseur of the Ombres House, he says 'You made the right choice, he was not to be trusted. I too dont like the Sabbath Family. Together we can get revenge'. Press Y to accept and N top refuse";
 } else {
 document.body.innerHTML = "He quickly slits your right wrist, and collects the blood spilled in a barrel. Soon nobles will enjoy this aged red. <br> <h1 style='text-align:center;'>GAME OVER<h1><br><h3 style='text-align:center;'>Press any key to continue...</h3>";
 window.addEventListener("keydown", startGame1, false);}}}}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot happening in your question, I am going to focus on what I assume to be the skipped screen. As far I can tell it should remove the event listener.

In your code you have this segment, which is supposed to wait for the player to press anykey.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", chance(1), false);
```

The problem is that you call the "chance" function immediately, instead of waiting.

If you want to be able to unbind that function again you have

```
function waitForChance() {
    chance(1)
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", waitForChance, false);
```

Then you can unbind that later with

```
window.removeEventListener("keydown", waitForChance, false);
```

Btw If I were you I would probably try to avoid unbinding and rebinding event listeners as much since it is error prone(and difficult to read). I would probably create a state system like this where you create objects and switch between them. I think it makes it clearer which functions belong to which state.

```js
// every state has 2 properties text and options
// text is what is displayed on the screen
// options contain the functions that are executed when the user presses a key
// if you want to bind a specific just bind enter that key in lower case
// if you want to accept any key add a function on anyKey 

//---------------- STATES --------------------------
let startState = {
  text: `<h4>As you are walking to the bar at a pub, a dark, hooded figure, pulls you aside to a corner: 'Listen, I have a job for you...'</h4><h2>Press 'Y' to accept, and 'N' to turn back to the bar</h2><img id='hoodedFigure' src='https://render.fineartamerica.com/images/rendered/default/print/6.125/8.000/break/images-medium/the-hooded-figure-kayleigh-semeniuk.jpg'>`,
  options: {
    y: function() {
      loadState(takeDealState)
    },
    n: function() {
      loadState(ambushState)
    }
  }
}

let takeDealState = {
  text: `What ever happend when you take the deal  (for now i reload the game on anykey)`,
  options: {
    /*Your options when you take the deal for now I just reset the game*/
    anyKey: function() {
      loadState(startState)
    }
  }
}

let ambushState = {
  text: `The strange figure draws his weapons and agresses on you. You draw your small blade, and attempt to slash his stomach.<h3 style='text-align:center;'>Press any key to continue...</h3>`,
  options: {
    anyKey: function() {
      var chance = Math.random(0.1, 1)
       if (chance >= 0.80) {
        loadState(successfullAmbush)
       } else {
        loadState(failedAmbush)
       }
    }
  }
}

let successfullAmbush = {
  text: `Suddenly a swaggering figure walks towards you he says intrduces himself as Jean-Jacques le Tourment des Ombres, Grand Connoisseur of the Ombres House, he says 'You made the right choice, he was not to be trusted. I too dont like the Sabbath Family. Together we can get revenge'. Press Y to accept and N top refuse`,
  options: {
    y: function() {
      console.log("accept")
    },
    n: function() {
      console.log("decline")
    }
  }
}

let failedAmbush = {
  text: `He quickly slits your right wrist, and collects the blood spilled in a barrel. Soon nobles will enjoy this aged red. <br> <h1 style='text-align:center;'>GAME OVER<h1><br><h3 style='text-align:center;'>Press any key to continue...</h3>`,
  options: {
    anyKey: function() {
      loadState(startState)
    }
  }
}

///---------------- LOGIC show and handle keypresses ---------------------------------- 
let currentState;

function loadState(state) {
  // set the state as the current state, so it can 
  currentState = state;
  // let the state descibe the scene
  document.body.innerHTML = state.text;
}

function keyHandler(event) {
  if(currentState.options.anyKey) {
    // handle anykey
    currentState.options.anyKey(event.key)
  } else if(currentState.options[event.key]) {
    // handle other key presses such as y/n
    currentState.options[event.key](event.key)
  }
}

window.addEventListener("keypress", keyHandler, true)

// start the game
loadState(startState)
```

Comment: If you are going to use your cide then i would probably unbind it at the beginning of the chance function.

Comment: it is not removing the event listener, so it doesn't skip the screen but once you get to Game over you can just press N to go back to when 'The figure agresses on you'. Where should I place the event listener to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the code on something like codepen? That way i can test what i recommend :)

Comment: I tried to set up the your code in codepen. https://codepen.io/frit007/pen/mgGRJy?editors=1010 @PythonNerd